# Newbie Need help Making Java to class and signing

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, javac, jar-signing

**Reason :** The programmer is not responding (or it is not in the contact now)  and i outsourced this project. So i have to do it my self.

**Knowledge level -** PHP, Some jquery Javascript Nothing else. Java is very new to me and not intended to learn.
I would like some help for signing applet

```
.java -> .class -> .jar -> Signing -> Signed.jar -> Adding to Website
```

Okay i think that will define purpose
So here is the procedure i did on pc

> Removed all Java JDK jRE ETC
>
> RESTARTED Now installed Just JDK (it
>   contains JRE by default) (the latest
>   version) that is it...

So i have .java file which is made by programmer.  For compiling it
.Java - .CLass

i did this

```
At command prompt


   javac MyNewApplet.java
    MyNewApplet.java:18: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : variable j
    location: class MyNewApplet
          j = paramString.charAt(i);
          ^
    MyNewApplet.java:19: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : variable j
    location: class MyNewApplet
          switch (j)
                  ^
```

Here is SOME source code of the file (MyNewApplet.java)

```
import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class MyNewApplet extends JApplet
{
  private String mv_decrypt(String paramString, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
    LinkedList localLinkedList1 = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < paramString.length(); i++)
    {
      j = paramString.charAt(i);
      switch (j)
      {
```

Can you kindly explain what is wrong ?

I got 30 errors 19 of them are of symbol. I didn't use java before but this is one where i am not able to by pass.

Comment: @userNNNN "Java is very new to me and not intended to learn."  Good for you.  In that case, I suggest you hire someone (more reliable than your original developer).

Comment: or perhaps ask the teacher for help.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Already invest good $ in this and i don't want to invest more. @MeBigFatGuy that is good suggestion but the thing is i don't have any one in contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of that specific error is that you have not declared the variable `j`.  Try changing that line to:

```
char j = paramString.charAt(i);
```

**See**

[Declaring Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) at The Java Tutorial.

Comment: i tried that it works for few thing but the code is complicated (for me) and so it is creating problems on other sides ...stil not able to compile..@krock if you can help me i can send you the code privately just tell me if u can so i will start the procedure of sending. It is Just one .java file also it is just 710 Lines of code.

Comment: Can any one suggest Where to get Professional help regarding java problem ?